# no puedo accerder a node_modules con gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

tengo una estructura de archivos y automatizacion de tareas con gulp.

Cuando corro la tarea default si me lee todos los archivos css incluyendo los que mando llamar de node_modules, pero cuando agrego la tarea browser-sync y corro de nuevo gulp no me lee ningun archivo css dejo a continuacion el codigo.

Estructura de archivos:

```
- build 
 -- development
  -- css 
  -- js 
  -- img 
  -- index.html 
- node_modules 
 -- animate.css
 -- (muchas otras) 
- src 
 -- templates 
 -- sass 
 -- img 
 -- js
```

En la carpeta templates tengo las vistas echas en con pug (jade)

Archivo gulp:

```
'use stric';

const gulp         = require("gulp"),
      pug          = require("gulp-pug"),
      sass         = require("gulp-sass"),
      babel        = require("gulp-babel"),
      imagemin     = require("gulp-imagemin"),
      svgmin       = require("gulp-svgmin"),
      webp         = require("gulp-webp"),
      useref       = require("gulp-useref"),
      concat       = require("gulp-concat"),
      uncss        = require("gulp-uncss"),
      autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
      cleanCSS     = require("gulp-uglify"),
      uglify       = require("gulp-uglify"),
      htmlmin      = require("gulp-htmlmin"),
      browserSync  = require("browser-sync").create();
      env          = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
      dir          = {
        src        : "src",
        build      : "build/development",
        production : "build/production",
        nm         : "node_modules"
      },
      files        = {
        CSS  : [
          `${dir.nm}/animate.css/animate.min.css`,
          `${dir.nm}/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css`,
          `${dir.build}/css/main.css`
        ],
        mCSS : "estilos.min.css",
        JS   : [
          `${dir.nm}/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`,
          `${dir.nm}/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js`,
          `${dir.nm}/wowjs/dist/wow.min.js`,
          `${dir.nm}/js/codigos.lojs`,
        ],
        mJS  : "codigos.min.js"
      },
      opts         = {
          pug : {
            pretty : true,
            locals : {
              title : "Titulo Loco",
              files : files
            }
          },
          sass : {
            outputStyle : "compressed"
          }
      };

// Task Pug
gulp.task("pug", () => {
  gulp
    .src( `${dir.src}/pug/*.pug`)
    .pipe( pug(opts.pug) )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dir.build}`))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream : true}));
});

// Task sass
gulp.task("sass", () => {
  gulp
    .src( `${dir.src}/sass/*.scss`)
    .pipe( sass(opts.sass) )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dir.build}/css`));
});

// Task watch
gulp.task("watch", () => {
  gulp.watch(`${dir.src}/pug/*.pug`, ["pug"]);
  gulp.watch(`${dir.src}/sass/*.scss` , ["sass"]);
});

//Task server
gulp.task("server", () => {
  browserSync.init({
    server : `${dir.build}`
  })
});

// Task default
gulp.task("default", ["pug", "sass", "server", "watch"]);
```

Archivo pug (html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="es")
head
  meta(charset="UTF-8")
  title Document
  each css in files.CSS
    link(rel="stylesheet", href=`../../${css}`)
body
  h1 probando desde jade
  p hola mundo
  each js in files.JS
    script(src=`../${js}`)
```

El codigo ejecutado con la tarea default eliminando la tarea server llama sin problema todos los archivos, pero al crear el server no llama los css

Comment: podrías especificar parte del error que te aparece?

Comment: no sale ningun error, solo cuando visualizas el archivo en localhost:3000 no se ven los css no carga nincun css

Comment: browserSync es una herramienta para el desarrollo, y en la tarea `server` estas apuntando a tus archivos construidos `build`.
No deberías ver los cambios realizados en tus archivos scss (`src`) en ves de apuntar a los  css (`dir`) directamente?

Comment: si, pero los archivos de src, con la tarea pug y sass se crean ya compilados dentro de build/development. Mandar llamar el css de ahi no tengo problema, el detalle es que la carpeta hermana de build es decir node_modules tiene estilos css que necesito llamar, pero cuando los mando llamar no los reconoce

**
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"/>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trata de pasar los parámetros `routes` y `baseDir` en el objeto `server`:

```
server: {
    baseDir: '${dir.build}',
    routes: {
        "/node_modules": '${dir.nm}',
    }
}
```

Luego incluye los estilos asi

```
<script src="node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"></script>
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, con esto resolví. Saludos JoseAPL

Comment: @salvadorGodinez puedes marcar la respuesta como resuelta en ese caso, ayudara a la comunidad a saber que respuesta es valida a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Quizás no sea un problema de gulp. Deberías fijarte si se puede acceder a esos .css desde la URL escribiendo directamente en el navegador:

```
localhost:3000/../../etc...css
```

con la URL esperada

Comment: El problema esta que sin la tarea server si funciona, solo cuando agrego la tarea server deja de funcionar (de cargar los css)